# How to create Product Type with multiple options

Tags: product, catalog, custom-options

I have a requirement where one of my category and its sub-category will contain a product having following options

For example, I am selling apparel and the `Tshirt` category contains products.

Custom T-shirt is an example of T-shirt where the product becomes complex in variations. It would contain the following

1. `11 Different Types of Color Options (no price change)`
2. `Each color will be combined with either white or black (no price
   change)`
3. `Only 3 sizes will be available (each size with different price)`

The product should be filtered in layered navigation with by `Custom T-Shirt`. On product detail page, the price will be shown based on the size selected by user.

How can I build above mentioned product type along with the `attribute set and attribute` ?

What would be the best practice in doing so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use configurables - yes it will create 1,000s to 10,000s of product combinations. You can also do it with custom options if you don't need inventory. You will need good hosting to go along with it due to the 10,000s of products.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this extension [Custom Option Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manger.html) provides following usability:

1)Add/remove custom option for multiple products from single page,

2)Add/remove custom option for multiple category products from single page.